# SQL Alchemy | Except Auto Increment ID

Tags: session, sqlalchemy

I have object that I created from sessionmaker. With this, I can add operations with add,commit,refresh. Every time I add the id it goes up by 1 as expected -1,2,3,..-. However, if an error occurs in the insertion process (like the existence of the same record), it is except and does not perform the record. But on the next successful save I notice that it incremented the id and skipped it. So like 16,17,19. It's skipping 18. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

SessionLocal.add(self)
SessionLocal.commit()
SessionLocal.refresh(self)
```

Comment: An integer primary key that gets autoincremented is a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), it has no business value other than identifying each records. So these missed increments **don't matter**. They should hardly ever be used by your application, besides internal work by the ORM.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ljmc. When I say it should not be used at all, edit/delete etc. should i use uuid in processes?

Answer (score 2):

To continue from my comment above:

> An integer primary key that gets autoincremented is a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), it has no business value other than identifying each records. So these missed increments **don't matter**. They should hardly ever be used by your application, besides internal work by the ORM.

You should not need to use the surrogate key ever, for they are surrogate, synthetic, **meaningless**.

They only help with stability and fast indexing (among others, read more in the link above) but have no relationship to the content/meaning of the record.

I actually believe that using surrogate keys to access records is an all too common code smell.

This example is pretty much where we create a User class, add a couple of User records, and select them with the natural key `username`, never using the surrogate key `id`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, Integer, String, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"User(username={self.username})"
        # NB. I don't even bother putting id in __repr__ most of the time

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True)  # add `echo=True` if you'd like

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(User(username="aliosmankepir"))
    session.add(User(username="ljmc"))
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    # get all User records
    print(session.scalars(select(User)).all())
    # filter with natural key
    print(session.scalars(select(User).filter_by(username="ljmc")).all())
```

I don't think I've ever used the `session.get(User, <pk>)` described in [Getting Objects by Primary Key from the Identity Map](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#getting-objects-by-primary-key-from-the-identity-map).